# How can I plot the residuals of lm() with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I would like to have a nice plot about residuals I got from an `lm()` model. Currently I use `plot(model$residuals)`, but I want to have something nicer. If I try to plot it with ggplot, I get the error message:

> ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Fortify is no longer recommended and might be deprecated according to Hadley.

You can use the broom package to do something similar (better):

```
library(broom)
y <-rnorm(10)
x <-1:10
mod <- lm(y ~ x)
df <- augment(mod)
ggplot(df, aes(x = .fitted, y = .resid)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: The augment function is not needed here or at least isn't anymore. The following produces the same result.
`mod <- lm(y ~ x)`  
`ggplot(mod, aes(x = .fitted, y = .resid)) + geom_point()`

Answer (score 17):

Use `ggfortify::autoplot()` for the `gg` version of the regression diagnostic plots. See this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfortify/vignettes/plot_lm.html).

---

## Example

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

library(ggfortify)
autoplot(fit)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`ggplot` wants a data.frame. `fortify` will make one for you.

```
y <-rnorm(10)
x <-1:10
mod <- lm(y ~ x)
modf <- fortify(mod)
ggplot(modf, aes(x = .fitted, y = .resid)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: you can also pass mod directly

Comment: the up-to-date option is to use `broom::tidy()`

Answer (score 4):

Now you can use the `ggResidpanel` package developed for creating ggplot type residual plots on CRAN. You can find the intro tutorial [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggResidpanel/vignettes/introduction.html)!